# Android SDK Manager - Failed to fetch

Tags: android, sdk, urlfetch

Error 1:

> Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host www.google.de

Error 2:

> Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host www.google.de

Can I download and insert this xml files manually?
Are then this problems solved?

Answer (score 0):

There are some people who has posted about downloading SDK tools without SDK manager.
[Like in this site.](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6588/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-internet-connection/)

But you should check your internet connection. I have same problem but after that i came to know that it was because of bad internet connection.

I have retried it and it was downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and here is what I did to solve the problem.

1. Since I use proxy server for accessing internet i have edited the file
   "C:\Users\.AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml" as

Notice the **PROXY_HOST** value there is no "**http://**" part, this is important. In my case when I insert that it did not work I did not know why.
2. I have edited the file
  "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat"

I have changed the line at the end of android.bat file from

```
call "%java_exe%   %REMOTE_DEBUG%" ....
```

to

```
call "%java_exe%  **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** %REMOTE_DEBUG%"...
```

Notice the value in bold